# post multi-select list to list of objects asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding, multi-select

I have two classes called `User` and `Role`.

```
class User
{
    ...
    public List<Role> Roles;
}

class Role
{
    ...
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

I also have an action (Submit)

```
public IActionResult Submit(User user)
{
    ...
}
```

in my Index.cshtml `select` is

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" asp-for="Roles" asp-items="ViewBag.Roles"></select>
```

and `ViewBag.Roles` value is

```
ViewBag.Roles= new SelectList(Role.SelectAll(), "Name", "Name");
```

the problem is that when I post my form, data is sent like this
`...&Roles=role1,role2&...`
and so `user.Roles` becomes null while I want to make two Roles with names `role1` and `role2` and assign them to `user.Roles` (Actually, I want Asp does that)

Answer (score 9):

The Select Tag Helper asp-for specifies the model property name for the select element, and asp-items specifies the option elements(a collection of SelectListItem ), rather than object collection.

1.Add a ViewModel with a List as the property for your dropdown items.

```cs
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<int> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

2.In.cshtml file select like below

```
@model PostMultiSelect.Models.UserViewModel
 <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" asp-for="@Model.Roles" asp-items="(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles"></select>
```

3.The value of ViewBag.Roles like below, get the Roles with RoleId

```cs
ViewBag.Roles = _context.Roles.Select(r=>new SelectListItem {Value=r.ID.ToString(),Text=r.Name}).ToList();
```

If you want to get Roles with name, you could change "*Value=r.ID.ToString()*" to"*Value=r.Name*"

Comment: I wouldn't use viewbag and instead make use of a property.

Comment: Hey! Did you found the solution? Does multi-select work for asp.net core razor pages from the scratch?

Answer (score 1):

In controller u have a list of roles:

```
 List<Roles> rolesList = new List<Roles>();
 roleList = _context.Roles.Tolist();
 ViewBag.Roles =rolesList;
```

In view:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" asp-for="Roles" asp-items=@(new MultiSelectList(@ViewBag.Roles, "IdRoles", "Roles"))></select>
```