# Insert to many-to-many relationship from view in asp.net core with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

So i have a view in my ASP.net Core application that i Add a new Car Repair and i want also to add Parts in this model. The Database has 3 tables : Repair - Parts - RepairParts.

I have managed to create the new repair but i have no idea how to pass a list of parts from this view to the controller and insert them in the RepairParts Table.

**Repair Class**

```
    public class Repair
    {
        [Key]
        public int RepairId { get; set; }

        public int VehicleId { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public string Mileage { get; set; }

        public DateTime RepairDate { get; set; }

        public string uuid { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RepairParts> Parts { get; set; }
    }
```

**Part Class**

```
public class Part
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RepairParts> Repairs { get; set; }
}
```

**RepairPart Class**

```
public class RepairParts
{
    public int RepairId { get; set; }
    public virtual Repair Repair { get; set; }

    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }

}
```

**Repair Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult 
    Create([Bind("VehicleId,Mileage,RepairDate,Notes")] RepairCreateModel repair)
    {
        try
        {
            Repair rep = new Repair();

            var NewRepair = _mapper.Map(repair, rep);

            _repairService.Add(NewRepair);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;

        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

**Repair Service**

```
    public void Add(Repair repair)
    {
        string userid = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        repair.uuid = userid;
        _context.Repairs.Add(repair);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Repair Create View**

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

<input asp-for="VehicleId" value="@ViewBag.VehicleId" type="hidden" />

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Owner</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Owner" 
readonly>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Vehicle</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Vehicle" 
readonly>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Licence Plates</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
value="@ViewBag.LicencePlates" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Mileage</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input asp-for="Mileage" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input asp-for="RepairDate" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Notes</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 row">
        <textarea asp-for="Notes" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Anyone has any idea how can i achieve that?

Comment: Few things in this but ill put you on the right track. Your view and view model will need setup with some thing like this answer (multi-select, you haven't specified what you are looking for so this is will be a basic selection) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973284/post-multi-select-list-to-list-of-objects-asp-net-core-2

This will then create a list of int's you can then use to create RepairParts. You can get the Id of the Report after its saved. Basic example but should help.

Comment: I dont think this can work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Okay you need to explain why this wont work for you.